# Question from P1 exam book - joint continuous gamma distribution. This is a question from the actuary P1 book

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

If X and Y are independent gamma random variables with parameters (α, λ)
and (β, λ) respectively, compute the joint density of U = X + Y and $$ V =
\frac{X}{X+Y} $$

I was stuck on how to find $$ f_U $$ and $$ f_V $$

for a while but was able to figure it out. I had seen some questions pertaining to parts of this problem or slightly different problems with people struggling and thought I should post it. The answer with my work is below. I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: @BrianTung I posted some more description... I hope that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f_{U,V}(u,v) = \frac {{ \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ {\frac{y}{(x+y)^2}} & {\frac{-x}{(x+y)^2}} \end{vmatrix}}^{-1} \cdot (uv)^{(\alpha -1)} \cdot \lambda^\alpha \cdot e^{-\lambda uv} \cdot (u-uv)^{\beta - 1} \cdot \lambda^\beta \cdot e^{-\lambda(u-uv)}} {\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)} $$
$$ = \frac { u \cdot (uv)^{(\alpha -1)} \cdot \lambda^\alpha \cdot e^{-\lambda uv} \cdot (u-uv)^{\beta - 1} \cdot \lambda^\beta \cdot e^{-\lambda(u-uv)}} {{\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)}}  $$

$$ = \frac {e^{-\lambda u} \cdot {u^{\alpha + \beta -1} \cdot \lambda ^{\alpha + \beta} \cdot v^{\alpha-1} \cdot (1-v)^{\beta -1}}} {\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)} $$

$$ f_U = \int_0^1   \frac {e^{-\lambda u} \cdot {u^{\alpha + \beta -1} \cdot \lambda ^{\alpha + \beta}  \cdot v^{\alpha-1} \cdot (1-v)^{\beta -1}}} {\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)} dv = \frac {e^{-\lambda u} \cdot u^{\alpha + \beta -1}\cdot \lambda ^ {\alpha + \beta}} {\Gamma(\alpha +\beta)} $$

Because $$ \int_0^1 v^{\alpha-1} \cdot (1-v)^{\beta -1} dv = \frac {\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)} {\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)} $$

$$ f_V = \int_0^\infty   \frac {e^{-\lambda u} \cdot {u^{\alpha + \beta -1} \cdot \lambda ^{\alpha + \beta} \cdot v^{\alpha-1} \cdot (1-v)^{\beta -1}}} {\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)} du = \frac{ v^{\alpha-1} \cdot (1-v)^{\beta-1} \cdot \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma (\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)}$$

Because we know $$  \int_0^\infty   \frac {e^{-\lambda u} \cdot {u^{\alpha + \beta -1} \cdot \lambda ^{\alpha + \beta}}} {\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)} du = 1 $$
And

$$ \frac{ v^{\alpha-1} \cdot (1-v)^{\beta-1} \cdot \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma (\alpha) \cdot \Gamma(\beta)} \cdot  \frac {e^{-\lambda u} \cdot u^{\alpha + \beta -1} \cdot \lambda ^ {\alpha + \beta}} {\Gamma(\alpha +\beta)} = f_{U,V}(u,v) $$

Hence U and V are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Jacobian Transformation theorem's method.

- If $X\sim {\rm Gamma}(\alpha,\lambda)$, with $\alpha>0$ and $\lambda>0$, then the density function for $X$ is given by
  $$f_{X}(x)=\frac{\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x},\quad x\in {\rm supp}(X).$$
- Suppose that  $X\sim {\rm Gamma}(\alpha,\lambda), Y\sim {\rm Gamma}(\beta,\lambda)$ and $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables.
- Define the random variables  $$U:=X+Y,\quad V:=\frac{X}{X+Y}$$
- Notice that we can re-write $(x,y)\mapsto u(x,y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto v(x,y)$ as $(u,v)\mapsto x(u,v)$ and $(u,v)\mapsto y(u,v)$ as follows
  $$\begin{cases}x=uv,\\y=u(1-v) \end{cases},\quad (u,v)\in U\times V$$
- The Jacobian of the change of variables is given by
  $$J(u,v)=\det \begin{pmatrix}x_{u}&x_{v}\\ y_{u}&y_{v} \end{pmatrix}=-u;\quad |J(u,v)|=u$$
- An important result says that if $U$ and $V$ continuous random variables, then $$U\quad \text{independent to}\quad  V\quad \text{iff}\quad  f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{U}(u) f_{V}(v),\quad (u,v)\in {\rm supp}(U\times V)$$
- The [Jacobian transformation theorem](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/03%3A_Distributions/3.07%3A_Transformations_of_Random_Variables), says that under certain hypotheses we have
  $$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f(x(u,v),y(u,v))|J(u,v)|$$
- *It is your task to check that all the hypotheses of the theorems used here are satisfied.*
- By hypothesis $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then
  \begin{align} 
  f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y),\\
  &=\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}e^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(x+y\right)}\cdot x^{\alpha-1}\cdot y^{\beta-1}\right],\quad (x,y)\in {\rm supp}(X\times Y)
  \end{align}
  and then by the Jacobian transformation theorem
  \begin{align}
  f_{U,V}(u,v)&=\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}e^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(uv+u-uv \right)}\cdot (uv)^{\alpha-1}\cdot (u-uv)^{\beta-1} \right]\cdot u,\\
  &=\left(\frac{u^{\alpha+\beta-1}e^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}u}}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} \right)\cdot \left(\frac{v^{\alpha-1}(1-v)^{\beta-1}}{{\rm Beta} (\alpha,\beta)}\right),\quad (u,v)\in {\rm supp}(U\times V),\\
  &=f_{U}(u)f_{V}(v),\quad \text{because}\quad {\rm Beta}(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}
  \end{align}
- Hence $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables.
- Moreover $$U\sim {\rm Gamma}(\alpha+\beta,\lambda)\quad \text{and}\quad V\sim {\rm Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$$

Comment: It should be the inverse of the absolute value of the Jacobean so just put a power to the -1...